# Tkinter: NameError when getting input from Entry

Tags: python, class, tkinter, nameerror

So the issue is when I click the `calc_button`, which calls the `calculate_tip` method, I get a `NameError` saying `'subtotal_entry' is not defined`. I have tried a bunch of different things to get this working but nothing has worked so far. I am trying to get the users input from the `Entry` I created called `subtotal_entry`.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class TipGUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Tip Calculator')

        #create the frames
        subtotal_frame = Frame(master).grid(row=0, column=0)
        percent_frame = Frame(master).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tip_frame = Frame(master).grid(row=2, column=0)
        button_frame = Frame(master).grid(row=3, column=0)
        total_frame = Frame(master).grid(row=4, column=0)

        #create the labels
        subtotal_label = Label(subtotal_frame, text="Enter the amount of the ticket:").grid(row=0, column=0)
        percent_label = Label(percent_frame, text="Enter the tip as a percent:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        tip_label = Label(tip_frame, text="Tip Amount: $").grid(row=2, column=0)
        tipAmt_label = Label(tip_frame, text="").grid(row=2, column=1)
        total_label = Label(total_frame, text="Total Amount: $").grid(row=3, column=0)
        totalAmt_label = Label(total_frame, text="").grid(row=3, column=1)

        #create entry boxes
        subtotal_entry = Entry(subtotal_frame).grid(row=0, column=1)
        percent_entry = Entry(percent_frame).grid(row=1, column=1)

        #create buttons
        calc_button = Button(button_frame, text="Calculate", command= self.calculate_tip).grid(row=4, column=0)
        exit_button = Button(button_frame, text="exit", command= master.quit).grid(row=4, column=1)

    def calculate_tip(self):
        subtotal = Entry.get(subtotal_entry)
        percent = percent_entry.get()

        if subtotal <= 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please enter a subtotal greater than 0")
            
        if percent <= 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please enter a tip percentage greater than 0")
            
        else:
            tip = subtotal * percent
            total = tip + subtotal

            tipAmt_label.config(text = format(tip, ',.2f'))
            totalAmt_label.config(text = format(total, ',.2f'))

            subtotal_entry.delete(0, END)
            percent_entry.delete(0,END)


#Create the window
window = Tk()
tipGUI = TipGUI(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `subtotal_entry` is a local variable. It shouldn't be.

Comment: Other than the scope issue, you have the common issue: [tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: `subtotal_entry` should be an instance attribute of your `TipGUI` class. i.e. `self.subtotal_entry`.

Answer (score 0):

You have few common problems.

1. `subtotal_entry` is local variable which can't be accessed in other functions. You have to use `self.subtotal_entry` to create variable which can be accessed in other functions in class.
2. `variable = Widget.grid()` assigns `None` to `variable` because `grid()`, `pack()`, `place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two steps

   ```
   variable = Widget()
   variable.grid()
   ```

   And if later you don't have to access some widget (some `Label`s) then you can skip `variable`

   ```
   Widget().grid()
   ```
3. To get value you need `subtotal_entry.get()` instead of `Entry.get(subtotal_entry)`
4. `Entry` gives string so you have to use `int()` or `float()` to convert string to value.

---

Full working code.

I assumed that `percent` will be value `0 ... 100`, not `0.00 ... 1.00`

I removed most of `Frames` because they were useless.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import messagebox

class TipGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Tip Calculator')

        #create the labels
        subtotal_label = tk.Label(master, text="Enter the amount of the ticket:")
        subtotal_label.grid(row=0, column=0, stick='e')
        
        percent_label = tk.Label(master, text="Enter the tip as a percent:")
        percent_label.grid(row=1, column=0, stick='e')
        
        self.tip_label = tk.Label(master, text="Tip Amount: $")
        self.tip_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        self.total_label = tk.Label(master, text="Total Amount: $")
        self.total_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        #create entry boxes
        self.subtotal_entry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.subtotal_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        
        self.percent_entry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.percent_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #create buttons
        frame_buttons = tk.Frame(master)
        frame_buttons.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        calc_button = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Calculate", command=self.calculate_tip)
        calc_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        exit_button = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Exit", command=master.quit)
        exit_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def calculate_tip(self):
        subtotal = float(self.subtotal_entry.get())
        percent = float(self.percent_entry.get()) / 100

        if subtotal <= 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please enter a subtotal greater than 0")
            
        if percent <= 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please enter a tip percentage greater than 0")
            
        else:
            tip = subtotal * percent
            total = tip + subtotal

            self.tip_label.config(text=f"Tip Amount: ${tip:,.2f}")
            self.total_label.config(text=f"Total Amount: ${total:,.2f}")

            self.subtotal_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            self.percent_entry.delete(0, 'end')

#Create the window
window = tk.Tk()
tipGUI = TipGUI(window)
window.mainloop()
```